# SharePoint Blog Post not displaying single post content

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation

I have a SharePoint 2010 foundation blog site. When I go to the main page I see the normal full list of posts, however when I click on the link it just displays a standard "List" web-part with each post listed individually.

The closest I can get to fixing it is clicking on a post, editing the page, adding the "Posts" list web part and changing the view to , however this will display all posts and not the single individual post.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks
MW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After quite a lot of searching online I found this resolution:
http://msfarmer.blogspot.co.uk/2010/12/how-to-recreate-corrupted-postaspx-page.html?showComment=1364908013524#c6374104866231620700

It's a bit of a complex procedure but it fixed the issue for me.

Thanks
Mark